# How to implement "Press back again to quit" feature?

Tags: android

some applications (like for example the Dolphin HD Browser) implement the following feature:

Pressing "Back" jumps back in the back stack. When the initial view/activity/fragment is shown and you press "Back", a `Toast` appears saying "Press Back again to quit" or something similar.

How could I implement this feature?

Comment: Look at the dev site, its clearly defined.

Comment: @JoxTraex: Thanks, I know about the developer site and I also know how to influence the back stack. I just thought this was some builtin feature.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Your question didn't mean that (about built-in feature). You asked "how to implement...".

Comment: @haibison: I know. What's your point?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I just thought if you edit the question, it will be more clear. If not, ignore my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the back-button event like so:

```
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    //Add your logic here
    return;
}
```

Now create a flag so your application won't close the first time it fires.
Finally end your activity by calling `finish();` on your activity.

For quickly showing Toasts use this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to quit", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
```

Provided that you're launching this code from your activity class. If not, try to get the context of your activity instead of using `this`.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to show a `Toast`, I was just wondering whether the feature was something builtin (turned on for example through a flag in the manifest).

Comment: No problem! It don't think Google will ever built something like this into Android, even though it's useful feature for some apps, it breaks the default rule about how applications/activities *should* work.

Comment: That's true, even though I consider it particularly useful, for example for a web browser, where pressing the Back button goes back in the history of web sites.

Answer (score 8):

At top in the class:

```
  int count = 0;
```

In your class's body:

```
public void onBackPressed() 
{
   if(count == 1)
   {
      count=0;
      finish();
   }
   else
   {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press Back again to quit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      count++;
   }

    return;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean to put the `count++;` inside the `else`-clause of the `if(count == 1)` statement.

Comment: no put outside there is not need to put count++ inside the else

Comment: But if the default value of `count` is `0`. When the the user presses the back button it will first execute `count++;` so the value is now `1`, it will then check if the value of `count` equals `1`, this is always true and the activity will call `finish()`. Or am I completely missing something here?

Comment: ya ya Sorry we must put count++ after the condition.
I m so hungry so i made this problem..
Sorry dear,,

Comment: Ok , what if I(or a kid) pressed it once(it sets to true) accidentally and after some gap of say 30sec~ > , I(or a kid again) presses back button. OMG it quits app in middle, but the question(or subject) here should be "QUIT AN APPLICATION ON CLICKING THE BACK BUTTON TWICE SUCCESSIVELY."In less than a maximum of 2~3 seconds, ELSE reset the FLAG = default values.

Answer (score 2):

For API level 1 override the activity's

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    ....
```

For API level 5 and above see what Pieter888 said.